# The following query returns line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

The following query returns:

```
line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'
```

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS adult_data_clean(
    age bigint,
    workclass string,
    education string,
    relationship string,
    occupation string,
    country string,
    income_cat string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
STORED AS OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 
    's3://census-income-example/clean.data'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'classification'='csv'
    'skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors:

- The `TBLPROPERTIES` is missing a comma between the parameters
- `OUTPUTFORMAT` should *not* have `STORED AS` before it (since it simply continues from `INPUTFORMAT`):

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS adult_data_clean(
    age bigint,
    workclass string,
    education string,
    relationship string,
    occupation string,
    country string,
    income_cat string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 
    's3://census-income-example/clean.data'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'classification'='csv',
    'skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

Yes, those error messages were confusing and misleading.